# ensure that the two rows In my bootstrap table are always side by side regardless of the length of text

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap panel with text within a table. One side of the text is links and the other is descriptions. What I notice is that I have to fake the length of the text sometimes to ensure that the text will appear next to the link/description.
How can I efficiently set up these rows so that the text will always be next to the designated link or description regardless of the length of the text? I need it to be flexible enough to still display on same line but obviously a different row

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading">
  <h4>Plan</h4>
</div>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Set project strategy, tactics and timing</th>
      <th><a href="" target="_blank">Project Brief</a></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Choose the right channel for your communication</th>
      <th><a href="" target="_blank">Channel Guidelines</a> &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj;&zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj;&zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Add your project to the calendar<br><br></th>
      <th><a href="" target="_blank">Communications Calendar Intake</a> </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Submit outbound call/text programs </th>
      <th><a href="" target="_blank">website to test</a></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Review vendor guidelines and share communication requirements with vendors</th>
      <th style="margin-left: 100px;"><a href="" target="_blank">Vendor Guidelines</a>  &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj;&zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj;&zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach you used wouldn't work on all screen resolutions... a better way is to use `vertical-align:middle`;

I have duplicated the 2 rows without the `&zwnj;` that you had added... These are colored green, and it is where I have used `vertical-align` property also;

**working snippet** below:

```css
.table thead td {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4>Plan</h4>
    </div>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Set project strategy, tactics and timing</th>
          <th><a href="" target="_blank">Project Brief</a></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Choose the right channel for your communication</th>
          <th><a href="" target="_blank">Channel Guidelines</a> &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj;&zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj;&zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Choose the right channel for your communication</th>
          <td><a href="" target="_blank">Channel Guidelines</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Add your project to the calendar<br><br></th>
          <th><a href="" target="_blank">Communications Calendar Intake</a> </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Submit outbound call/text programs </th>
          <th><a href="" target="_blank">website to test</a></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Review vendor guidelines and share communication requirements with vendors</th>
          <th style="margin-left: 100px;"><a href="" target="_blank">Vendor Guidelines</a> &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj;&zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj;&zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj; &zwnj;</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Review vendor guidelines and share communication requirements with vendors</th>
          <td style="margin-left: 100px;"><a href="" target="_blank">Vendor Guidelines</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```